# Evaluating $\iint_{[0,1]^2}\big\{\frac{k}{x-y}\big\}\big\{\frac{1}{x}\big\}\big\{\frac{1}{y}\big\}\, dx dy $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I was working on this integral which I found on Quora [here](https://nikhil.quora.com/If-math-k-math-is-a-positive-real-number-and-math-math-denotes-the-fractional-part-then-how-can-you-evaluate?ch=10&share=abf2bfc9&srid=ufjwhF) where $k$ is a positive real number.
$$ I = \iint_{[0,1]^2}\bigg\{\frac{k}{x-y}\bigg\}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}\bigg\{\frac{1}{y}\bigg\}\, dx dy $$
I noted that the first fractional part is $0$ for $k$ being an integer multiple of $x-y$. So, while evaluating the integral, I made the assumption that this isn't the case.
Using $\{x\}+\{-x\}=1$ which I found on the Wikipedia page of fractional part, and the fact that $x$ and $y$ can be interchanged in the integral, I got
$$I = \frac{1}{2}\left( \int_0^1 \bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}\, \mathrm dx \right)^2$$
And finally using the result
$$\int_0^1 \bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\}\, \mathrm dx=1-\gamma$$
I got $I = \frac{(1-\gamma)^2}{2}$.
The person who asked the question says that this is the correct result. But, I have a feeling that the original assumption is problematic, but I don't know if this is actually the case.

Can you tell me if the assumption is problematic or not? Why?

Comment: It excludes a measure-zero set. That usually won't affect the integral.

Comment: @Trebor, can you please shortly explain what a measure zero set is?

Comment: Intuitively it's just a very small set, like a point is to a line, or a line is to an area. But there is no simple explanation without defining what a measure is.

Comment: @Trebor then what is measure of something, in simple terms?

Comment: A measure $\mu$ of a space $X$ is simply a function from $X$ to non-negative real numbers (including infinity in some versions), that satisfy certain properties we expect of areas, lengths, etc.

Comment: What is said here about a measure-zero set is true for the Lebesgue integral. Changing a Riemann-integrable function on a set of measure zero can result in a non-Riemann-integrable function (though if the function remains integrable, the value doesn't change). The correct notion for Riemann integration is a set of Jordan content zero. This means, in the two-dimensional case, that for any number $\varepsilon > 0$, no matter how small, the set can be covered by finitely many rectangles of total area $< \varepsilon$. The definition of a set of measure zero is similar, but you can have....

Comment: countably many rectangles instead of finitely many. To summarize, if you modify a Riemann-integrable function on a set of content zero, in such a way that the function remains bounded, then it remains Riemann-integrable with the same integral.

Comment: @Anonymous the assumption I made itself seems wierd. You can argue that there are infinitely many values $k$ which would satisfy my assumption, but also there are infinitely many values of $k$ which won't. The thing to wonder is that which of the two infinities is bigger and by how much. That can either justify or disprove my assumption.

Comment: In this problem, I believe $k$ is a fixed positive number, right?